# How to stop derive file from generating new info?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, derived

I get the error ld: 89 duplicate symbols for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
and from what I've researched it seems the error is from the derived file but when I delete it new data gets created how do I stop it from creating new file, data etc? (it also seems related to Cocoapods or firebase)

my pod file:`# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project 
target 'yeeeeeer' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!`

`# Pods for yeeeeeer
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.2.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'          end`

Comment: XCode stores intermediate builds, build targets, and the project index so it wouldn't be a good idea to stop it from generating new info. Have you tried cleaning the project and then building? (Shift + Command + K)

Comment: yes i have doesn't work.

Comment: Could you post the full error log?

Comment: just before i do it seems like its not working because i have an older version of pods pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.2.1' but I'm on Xcode 7.3.1 and an older mac so the newer pods don't work normally which forces me to use this version

Comment: " from what I've researched it seems the error is from the derived file " Not always the case. If you really need to remove derived files each times yes, but if not there may be an issue on your podFile/configuration.

Comment: like what? ill edit the post to show my pod file

Comment: this is my logs https://docs.google.com/document/d/10SHTum-s5hDxqisFXmlzQtGpqRu7r9Nybo1GC6nEaBY/edit?usp=sharing